# What's the behavior of sizeof used in member initializer?

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof

What's the behavior of sizeof used in member initializer? I can't find a description about exactly that. In the below code example is it safe? ie, after `struct` member will the compiler put right size of `A` in `b`?

```
struct A
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = sizeof(A);
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    char s[256];

    A()
    {
        //printf("b = %d\n", b);
    }
};
```

Comment: Should work correctly. Struct declaration is not dependent on the initializer so the sizeof would be filled in during creation of the struct at which time the size of the struct is known.

Comment: You should try it with something more interesting. Add in a map or something.

Comment: How does "add in a map" make any difference at all? A `std::map` has a fixed size when it comes to `sizeof`. It may then have a dynamic size that varies, but this is completely irrelevent. As long as the compiler knows the definition of the `class` or `struct`, it will work just fine. You can not have elements with unknown size at all inside any other type. This is why you have to use pointers or references to objects that haven't been fully defined yet.

Comment: Name lookup inside NSDMIs is postponed until after the class is complete, just like name lookup inside member functions [basic.lookup.unqual]/8. Also, the evaluation of those initializers happens "inside the mem-initializer-list" [class.base.init]/8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a `struct` is determined much earlier in the compilation than the setting of the values inside the `struct`.

Comment: Note that this is because the initializer for non-static members actually has the same scope as you'd get in the definition of the constructor. If the code tried `struct A { static constexpr int i = sizeof(A); };` then it wouldn't work because that initializer is in a different scope and the type is incomplete there.